# Issue with Angular HTTP request to ASP.NET Core API: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: typescript, web, cors, backend

Description:
I'm encountering an issue while trying to make an HTTP POST request from an Angular application to an ASP.NET Core API. The error message I'm receiving is net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I've checked my code and configurations, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the problem.

Code:
Angular Service (auth.service.ts):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseServerUrl = 'https://localhost:44396/api/';

  registerUser(){
    return this.http.post(this.baseServerUrl + 'User/CreateUser',null,{
      responseType:'text',
    });
  }
  
}
```

Angular Component (register.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  repeatPass: string = 'none';
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  registerForm = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z].*")]),
    lastname: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z].*")]),
    email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    mobile: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"),
      Validators.minLength(10), 
      Validators.maxLength(10),
    ]),
    gender: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
    pwd: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6),
      Validators.maxLength(15),
    ]),
    rpwd: new FormControl(""),
  });

  registerSubmitted(){
    if(this.PWD.value == this.RPWD.value){
      console.log(this.registerForm.valid);
      this.repeatPass='none'

      this.authService.registerUser().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })

    }
    else{
      this.repeatPass='inline'
    }
  }

  get FirstName() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('firstname') as FormControl;
  }
  get LastName() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('lastname') as FormControl;
  }
  
  get Email() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('email') as FormControl;
  }
  
  get Mobile() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('mobile') as FormControl;
  }

  get Gender() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('gender') as FormControl;
  }
  get PWD() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('pwd') as FormControl;
  }
  get RPWD() : FormControl{
    return this.registerForm.get('rpwd') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

ASP.NET Core Startup Configuration (Startup.cs):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace Register
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }


    }
}
```

UserController.cs

```
namespace Register.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public UserController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpPost("CreateUser")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return Ok("Success from Create Method");
        }
    }
}
```

[This the Error displayed on my Devloper tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHTEH.png)

1. Checked API Endpoint: Ensured that the API endpoint (https://localhost:44396/api/User/CreateUser) is correct and accessible.

2.CORS Configuration:Verified CORS configuration in the ASP.NET Core API (Startup.cs) to allow requests from http://localhost:4200.

3.Development Server:Confirmed that the Angular development server is running without errors (ng serve).

4.Network Connection:Ensured there are no network-related issues, and the API is reachable.